# When I run my python script the jpg file used in it becomes jpg.REMOVE_ME. What can I do?

Tags: python, instagram

I am programming a Instagram bot, which automatically posts images. When I run it the first time it works then it makes the .jpg file to a .jpg.REMOVE_ME file. What can I do?

This is my code:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()

while True:

    bot.login(username="username",
          password="password")
   
    bot.upload_photo("E:\lol.jpg",
                 caption="lol ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply comment line 190 and 191 in api_photo.py file
path: instabot\api\api_photo.py

The code which needs to be commented in line 190-191:

```
        # if options.get("rename"):
        #     os.rename(photo, "{fname}.REMOVE_ME".format(fname=photo))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior:

> After successful upload, temporary photo will be renamed to {photo_name}.CONVERTED.jpg.REMOVE_ME in media folder

https://github.com/ohld/igbot/tree/master/examples/photos

BTW: Your code keep uploading the same picture.
If you want to upload another photo - update your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of:

- Rename it back.
- Before the upload, copy it. Then upload the copy. Then remove the renamed copy.
- Modify your local copy of the source code of instabot, and remove the codd which does the rename.